# Why the complete character array is getting printed not the first character?

Tags: c, pointers

This is the source code

```
char target[80]="hello", *tar;
tar=&target;
printf("%s",tar);  //printing hello
```

`tar` is getting the address of `target[0]` then why it is printing the whole character array.

Comment: Because you are telling it to print a string -> `%s`.

Comment: Because that's how strings work in C. They're a pointer to the first character in the string.

Comment: What are you expecting to see as output? Your code will print "hello" to stdout. The %s format tells printf to print all characters until reaching the null terminator (indicating the end of the string). In addition, your code might produce a compiler warning regarding assignment from incompatible pointer.

Comment: Also `tar=&target;` is Wrong. Even though `target` and `&target` have the same address.

Answer (score 2):

when u say %s and specify a starting memory(or any intermediate) of the string it gets printed till it encounters '\0' character.

consider

```
    char *name = "Hello";
```

will be stored internally as 
        Hello\0

so if u need a single character go for %c.

Answer (score 1):

Use %c to print a single character and %s is used to print a string.

Comment: But you also have to ensure you pass a `char` and not a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

C strings are null terminated. When you pass the address of the first character in an array of characters representing a string to `printf` and tell it to format the output as a string using `%s`, it will print all of the characters beginning at the address of the first character until a null (NUL) character, `'\0'`, is reached.

Answer (score 0):

%s indicates printing characters between the character 'tar' points to and next '\0' .

> printf("%c",*tar);

will print what you need.